# How To Iterate with Complex JSON and FTL

Tags: json, freemarker

I have a JSON where I should prepare a HTML on basis of that. Please find my JSON below

```
{
    "apiName": "myapi-v10",
    "eventKey": "monitor_records",
    "emailSubject": "local: PLAYER Records",
    "customFields": {
        "x_transaction_id": "9f99a9b0-30f5-11ea-8347-381c20524153",
        "emailData": {
            "Table 1": {
                "title": "Some X",
                "headers": [
                    "COUNT",
                    "PLAYER",
                    "STATUS"
                ],
                "data": [
                    {
                        "COUNT": 4,
                        "PLAYER": "APLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Open"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 2,
                        "PLAYER": "APLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Waiting"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 3,
                        "PLAYER": "CPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 2,
                        "PLAYER": "CPLAYER,
                        "STATUS": "withheld"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 3,
                        "PLAYER": "NPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 2,
                        "PLAYER": "NPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "provationsiu"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 4,
                        "PLAYER": "WPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "boost"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 1,
                        "PLAYER": "WPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "No Status"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Table 2": {
                "Title": "Some Y",
                "Headers": [
                    "COUNT",
                    "PLAYER",
                    "STATUS"
                ],
                "data": [
                    {
                        "COUNT": 4,
                        "PLAYER": "APLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Open"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 2,
                        "PLAYER": "APLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 3,
                        "PLAYER": "CMH",
                        "STATUS": "Closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 2,
                        "PLAYER": "CMH",
                        "STATUS": "withheld"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 3,
                        "PLAYER": "NPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "Closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 4,
                        "PLAYER": "WPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "boost"
                    },
                    {
                        "COUNT": 1,
                        "PLAYER": "WPLAYER",
                        "STATUS": "No Status"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to loop through customFields->emailData tables and access each value in it. I tried multiple ways but none seems to work out and throws the below exception.

```
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence
```

FTL Code snippet being used as below

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sas-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
    <#assign tableValues = customFields.emailData?values>
    <#assign tableKeys = customFields.emailData?keys/>
    <#list tableKeys as tableKey>
        <#assign seq_index = tableKeys?seq_index_of(tableKey) />
        <#assign tableValue = tableValues[seq_index]/>
        <table class="demo">
            <caption>${tableValue.title}</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <#list tableValue.headers as header>
                        <th>${header}</th>
                    </#list>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <#assign rows = table.data>
                <#list rows as row>
                    <tr>
                        <#list tableValue.headers as header>
                            <td>${row[header]}</td>
                        </#list>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </#list>
</div>
```

**Note: I'm using 2.3.23 freemarker version and upgrading or downgrading to other version is not possible as this takes lot of approvals.**

Also any suggestions to modify JSON which will result in easier ftl code are welcome.

It fails while trying to parse at title itself.

Exception Trace:

```
Jan 08, 2020 11:05:32 AM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger error
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
==> tableValue  [in template "monitorapi-success.template" at line 30, column 52]

----
Tip: Maybe using obj.something(params) instead of obj.something will yield the desired value
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${tableValue.title}  [in template "monitorapi-success.template" at line 30, column 50]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.NonHashException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:45)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:240)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
    at TestEmailTemplate.main(TestEmailTemplate.java:24)

Exception in thread "main" FreeMarker template error:
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
==> tableValue  [in template "monitorapi-success.template" at line 30, column 52]

----
Tip: Maybe using obj.something(params) instead of obj.something will yield the desired value
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${tableValue.title}  [in template "monitorapi-success.template" at line 30, column 50]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.NonHashException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:45)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:240)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
    at TestEmailTemplate.main(TestEmailTemplate.java:24)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `customFields.emailData` that throws the exception? Can show the whole exception error message?

Comment: Another thing, not directly related to the error. Since `tableKey` is a string, you could just write `<#assign tableValue = customFields[tableKey]>`; no need for `tableValues`, and dealing with indexes. (And, with 2.3.25 it would be even easier, but as you say you can't upgrade.)

Comment: I dont think  customFields[tableKey] will work as my tableKey are the keys that are inside customFields->emailData Object

Comment: Also yes I even tried with customFields.emailData[tableKey] but still no luck

Comment: Right, sorry... so then `customFields.emailData[tableKey]`. The point is that you need not find entries by numerical index.

Comment: As of what's shown in the stack trace, seems that the data-model doesn't look the way you think it does. Like if the value associated with `"Table 1"` was an JSON array. Maybe you get the table rows there directly, instead of under the "data" subvairable? You should try discover what are the items if you `#list` the table, instead of getting its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed when I convert the JSON to HashMap.